# Surface gl-react-native not displaying any content or crashing

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have been trying to use the Surface of gl-react-native class to see what's the output but whenever I tried to run the code snippet either the app crashes or the app is running but the display is only a white screen.

Here is my code:

```
import { Shaders, Node, GLSL } from "gl-react";
import { Surface } from "gl-react-native";

import React from "react";
import { Shaders, Node, GLSL } from "gl-react";
const shaders = Shaders.create({
  helloBlue: {
    frag: GLSL`
precision highp float;
varying vec2 uv;
uniform float blue;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(uv.x, uv.y, blue, 1.0);
}`
  }
});
class HelloBlue extends Component {
  render() {
    const { blue } = this.props;
    return <Node shader={shaders.helloBlue} uniforms={{ blue }} />;
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Surface width={300} height={300}>
        <HelloBlue blue={0.5} />
      </Surface>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "buffer": "^5.5.0",
    "expo-permissions": "^8.1.0",
    "gl-react": "^4.0.1",
    "gl-react-headless": "^4.0.1",
    "gl-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.7.0"
  }
```

In this case I get only a white screen as output:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Shaders, Node, GLSL } from "gl-react";
import { Surface } from "gl-react-native";

import React from "react";
import { Shaders, Node, GLSL } from "gl-react";
const shaders = Shaders.create({
  helloBlue: {
    frag: GLSL`
precision highp float;
varying vec2 uv;
uniform float blue;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(uv.x, uv.y, blue, 1.0);
}`
  }
});
class HelloBlue extends Component {
  render() {
    const { blue } = this.props;
    return <Node shader={shaders.helloBlue} uniforms={{ blue }} />;
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Surface style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}>
        <HelloBlue blue={0.5} />
      </Surface>
    );
  }
}
```

When I run this code the app doesnt respond at all and when I run it on the emulator the app crashes.

Comment: Could you try to add thee surface in VIEW component of the react-native.

Comment: Tried this also @NitinKumar, nothing happens, it displays a white screen only.

Answer (score 0):

get the versions correct

```
npm i --save react-native-gl-image-filters
npm i --save gl-react@^4.0.1
npm i --save gl-react-native@^4.0.1
npm i --save buffer@^5.4.3
npm i --save react-native-unimodules@^0.7.0
```

unimodules ^0.10.1 will also work